# Design pattern for data exchange

Tags: c++, oop, qt, design-patterns, signals-slots

I have a set of the virtual devices (D).
Devices can be cross-connected (assume, physical connect):

D1 -- D2

D2 -- D3

Each link possibly will have different latency.

Each device contains a set of virtual sub-devices (s) which can generate some data.
Sub-devices can be organized to logical connections.
Sub-devices will transmitt real byte-data.

I use C++, Qt.
I tried to use signal-slot mechanism, QSignalMapper, but I didn't find good solution.

Please, help me to build clear abstraction.
Can I use any design pattern?

Comment: You have virtual devices which are physically connected and have latency? Are you simulating a network or what are those devices?

Comment: Its not real clear what sort of `connection` or `link` you are looking for between the virtual devices. Do they just need to be able to call methods on each other? Additionally, what role do the sub-devices play?

Comment: OK, for the beginning let be Device (D) is a container(group) of sub-devices (s). Probably in the future I'll add special properties to devices(groups). The most interst question: How can I describe the link in OOP? Which can carry data to devices, can be delayed, etc. And how can I link the Data and Device classes?

Comment: You could have a Connection class, taking two QIODevice's and shoveling the data from one QIODevice to the other.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Thanks! Definitly I should inherit my Device class from QIODevice base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a `Link` class simulating a physical link between your classes. The most interesting question is, how to connect your devices and simulate the delay using signal and slots?

My suggestion is: Implement a `send(QByteArray data)` slot, which enqueues the data to an internal queue (simulating the wire) and sets a timeout to a given default delay with optional jitter. The timeout then fires a signal with the data popped from the queue.

If you want to simulate routers between the devices, you should take into account that the more data is in the queue, the bigger the delays become, since retransmissions need to be done. To simulate this approximately, you could make the timeout value depending on the current queue length.

Take this as a start:

```
class Link : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Link(Device *from, Device *to) :
        QObject(to), m_from(from), m_to(to)
    {
        //make my life dependant on both "from" and "to" objects
        connect(from, SIGNAL(destroyed()), SLOT(deleteLater()));

        //connect to the signals and slots of the devices
        connect(from, SIGNAL(send(QByteArray,Device*)),
                this, SLOT(  send(QByteArray,Device*)));
        connect(this, SIGNAL(receive(QByteArray,Device*,int)),
                to,   SLOT(  receive(QByteArray,Device*,int)));
    }

public slots:
    void send(QByteArray data, Device *receiver) {
        Message msg(data, 0, qobject_cast<Device*>(sender()), receiver);
        send(msg);
    }
    void send(Message msg) {
        msg.hops++; // here we increase the hops counter
        m_queue.enqueue(msg);
        QTimer::signalShot(m_delay, this, SLOT(timeout()));
    }

signals:
    void receive(QByteArray data, Device *sender, int hops);
    void forward(Message);

private slots:
    void timeout() {
        receive(m_queue.dequeue());
    }
    void receive(Message msg) {
        if(msg.receiver == m_to)
            // msg reached destination!
            emit receive(msg.data, msg.sender, msg.hops);
        else
            // forward to next link
            emit forward(msg);
    }

private:
    static const int m_delay = 100; // delay set to 100 ms
    QQueue<Message> m_queue;
    Device *m_from, *m_to;
};
```

The type `Message` is defined as follows:

```
struct Message {
    QByteArray data;
    int hops;
    Device *sender;
    Device *receiver;
    Message(data, hops, sender) : data(data), hops(hops),
                                  sender(sender), receiver(receiver) {}
};
```

Then just create devices and links like this:

```
// Create devices:
Device *d1 = new Device(this);
Device *d2 = new Device(this);

// Create link:
Link *d1d2 = new Link(d1, d2);
```

Or chained links with forwarding rules:

```
// Create devices:
Device *d1 = new Device(this);
Device *d2 = new Device(this);
Device *d3 = new Device(this);

// Create links:
Link *l1 = new Link(d1, d2);
Link *l2 = new Link(d2, d3);

// Create forwarding rule:
connect(l1, SIGNAL(forward(Message)), l2, SLOT(send(Message)));
```

Every data sent by d1 (when it emits the signal `send(QByteArray)`) will then be transferred with a delay of 100 ms to the slot `receive(QByteArray)` of d2. If the data wasn't for d2, the signal `forward(Message)` gets emitted, which has to be caught by another link (see forwarding rule). It then gets treated as a new incoming message and delivered to d3.

Note that real networks don't function like that. You'd need to implement routing strategies to fully simulate such a setup; which is quite difficult.

Also note that I didn't test this code. ;)

This approach doesn't simulate splitting the data into small segments (of abount 1.5 KB each). To simulate a real Ethernet setup, you'd need to do this, too. Ask in the comments if you need to, and I may extend the class.

Comment: Nice, this is a good start point. Your Link class is very clear. But if I'll have a tree of devices, can I connect Link's to chains? How can I send data through several links so the recipient knows who was the first sender? May be we need to create Message class, which travels through Links, counts hops, marks Device's as passed and etc.

Comment: @legotron see my updated answer. As you can see, it gets complicated now ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I'm trying to tweak and test your example.

Comment: I can't remember why I implemented `Link::receive` as a slot. Maybe there are some other mistakes in the code. If you are done testing, let me hear about it, and I'll update the answer for future readers. :)

Comment: Certainly. Now I success built the code and added some qDebug outputs to tests. When it'll work fine I'll send it to you. Should I place the corrected code in comments?

Comment: You can mail it to my address: stackexchange@leemes.de. I'll then put the code in the answer. (Comments are very limited in the length.)

Comment: Since I received your mail I'm glad it worked. I updated the code with the member variables for the two devices.